# Calling function inside condition - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to call function inside condition in render function, **only if condition is true**.

On line #3 of following code.

```
{this.props.xarray.map((heading, index) => 
        {return heading.headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1 ?
            {this.setcheckstate()} //THIS IS FUNCTION
            <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index} selected>{heading.headingis}</option>
            :
            <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index}>{heading.headingis}</option>
         }
    )}
```

But this is returning error:

> Syntax error: this is a reserved word (51:10)

I want to change the state if condition is true.

Comment: what does the function do? what does it return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you drop the ternarny ? It's sometimes clearer and cleaner to write a plain `if` statement IMO.

```
{
  this.props.xarray.map((heading, index) => {
    if (heading.headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1) {
      this.setcheckstate();
      return <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index} selected>{heading.headingis}</option>
    }

    return <option value="{heading.headingis}" key={index}>{heading.headingis}</option>
  })
}
```

Comment: It says unexpected token `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the condition outside of the return because that is not valid syntax.

Comment: It is working fine if i don't add `{this.setcheckstate()}`

Comment: Yes, but exactly that is what you want to put outside... this code: {this.setcheckstate()}...

Answer (score 1):

It will be like this,
Outside return of render method

```
 const { xarray } = this.props;
```

Inside the return method of render()

```
{xarray.map((heading, i) => {
  const { headingis } = heading;
  const condition = headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1;
  return (
    condition && this.setCheckState() ? 
        <option value={headingis} key={i} selected>{headingis}</option> :
        <option value={headingis} key={i}>{headingis}</option> :
  );
}}
```

I am sorry I did all the destructing, but it's just a habit, i like clean code. Anyways if you only want to show a selected based on a condition, you can also do something like this as well.

```
{xarray.map((heading, i) => {
  const { headingis } = heading;
  const condition = headingis.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') != -1;
  return (
    condition && <option 
                   value={headingis} 
                   key={i} 
                   selected={() => this.setCheckState}
                 >
                   {headingis}
                 </option>
  );
})}
```

Comment: After implementing you `above code #1` it gives error, `Unexpected token }}` at the end.

Comment: I corrected the syntax, it was missing a ```)``` in the last line. :)